# How do i determine the related column between tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have two tables. I need to find the column(s) that relate them. There are not any foreign keys. The primary key for 'CUSTTABLE' is 'ACCOUNTNUM' and for 'DIRPARTYTABLE' is 'RECID'. The related columns are 'CUSTTABLE.PARTY' and 'DIRPARTYTABLE.RECID'. I need this to return 'CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM', 'DIRPARTYTABLE.NAME', 'DIRPARTYTABLE.PARTYNUMBER' on the same line. The code I have returns column names that match. However, the names are often never the same in my case.

Is there a similar way to return the columns with matching values, not names? even if it returns multiple columns that would help. In reality, these tables have 100+ columns and I have many tables to determine the same type of relationship.

CUSTTABLE:

```
ACCOUNTNUM     CUSTGROUP   PARTY

305342         LTL         5637459693
305343         LTL         5637468513
305345         LTL         5637472531
305398         LTL         5637468514
305405         LTL         5637468515
```

DIRPARTYTABLE:

```
NAME                PARTYNUMBER   RECID

ZEP MFG             1500121      5637459693
TABER EXTRUSIONS    1500122      5637459694
LAWSON PRODUCTS     1500123      5637459695
KIMRAY              1500124      5637459696
ANCHOR PAINT MFG    1500125      5637459697
```

RESULT:

```
ACCOUNTNUM    NAME        PARTYNUMBER
305342        ZEP MFG     1500121
```

Query:

```
select A.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B
  on A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
where A.TABLE_NAME = 'CUSTTABLE'
  and B.TABLE_NAME = 'DIRPARTYTABLE'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You match on column names that exist in both tables. Yet, in `CUSTTABLE`, the column is called `PARTY`, where in `DIRPARTYTABLE` the column is `RECID`. So the query you wrote is not going to help you here.

As for trying to somehow match based on matching data, that's a terrible idea. You probably have a number of lookup tables that all have an id column. id numbers between these tables will exist in multiple tables, and your script would return nonsensical data.

If you aren't sure which columns relate, find the productowner of the application.

Comment: Based on what you've described, the answer is NO.

Comment: I think you could do it by writing a script that takes a list of all the table, column pairs and then for each get a few values from the column, then loop through each other table, column pair of the same type to check if there are any matching entries. If so, print "table A, column A => table B, column B" so you can verify the relationship manually. Then when you're happy, add a foreign key constraint or something. Will be a lot of work even with the script.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are working on D365 Database, in that case, usually `DIRPARTY` table contains all the info i.e. Employee, Customer, Vendor etc.. these would be filtered by `DIRPARTY.INSTANCERELATIONTYPE`. For the Customers `CUSTTABLE.PARTY` = `DIRPARTYTABLE.RECID` while `INSTANCERELATIONTYPE` = 1155 or 5767, This is standard info, you may want verify INSTANCERELATIONTYPE match with your setup.

Regarding relationship identification, I would suggest you to go through `form properties - query` from D365 application it self, otherwise it would be difficult to predict the relationship without verifying actual data unless you have **meta data document** available, because sometime we cannot relay on one column for key relation. i.e. `VENDOR.ACCOUNTID` is not key column unless you consider `VENDOR.ENTITYID` or `VENDOR.DATAAREAID`.

However, following query might be helpful as starting point. You can find similar name column in various number of tables excluding the tables that doesn't have any records.

```
with CTE as 
(
SELECT                  DB_ID () DatabaseID,
                        t.Name AS TableName,
                        p.rows AS RowCounts,
                        SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TblTotalSizeKB, 
                        SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB 
                    --  CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
                    FROM  
                            sys.tables as t
                        INNER JOIN      
                            sys.indexes i ON  t.Object_ID = i.object_id
                        INNER JOIN 
                            sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
                        INNER JOIN 
                            sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
                        --LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                        --  sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                    WHERE t.OBJECT_ID > 255 and p.rows > 0 --and T.name like '%WORKFLOWTRACKINGSTATUSTABLE%'   -----------Enter TABLE name (search key word) here
                    GROUP BY T.name, p.Rows
) 
select  C.COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE, CTE.*
from    CTE
        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C on CTE.TableName = C.TABLE_NAME
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Hire%'  -----------Enter COLUMN name (search key word) here
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME 
GO
```